# Itext7 Copy Layer from one PDF to another

Tags: itext7

How to add layer.getPdfObject() to another PDF (PDFDocument). My use case is to copy a layer from one pdf to another.

Comment: Please add details to your question including sample PDFs, code and more verbose explanation of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have a PDF file which has three layers with image and text in different colors. I have a requirement to to merge this pdf in middle of another pdf but also maintain the layers as is...I tried 'PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfDocument) but it just extracts text without image and layers. Hope it clarifies.